# How to interpret an array into squere bracket of another array?

Tags: python, arrays

I've write this code and I'm trying to understand the meaning of the output to apply a mask to an array

```
matrix = np.random.rand(3,3)
matrix

output:

array([[0.7441097 , 0.02908848, 0.60378581],
       [0.53335156, 0.21701412, 0.51545259],
       [0.91777356, 0.49123304, 0.15410852]])
```

```
mask

output:

matrix([[0, 0, 2],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 2]])
```

```
matrix[mask]

output:

array([[[0.7441097 , 0.02908848, 0.60378581],
        [0.7441097 , 0.02908848, 0.60378581],
        [0.91777356, 0.49123304, 0.15410852]],

       [[0.53335156, 0.21701412, 0.51545259],
        [0.53335156, 0.21701412, 0.51545259],
        [0.7441097 , 0.02908848, 0.60378581]],

       [[0.91777356, 0.49123304, 0.15410852],
        [0.91777356, 0.49123304, 0.15410852],
        [0.91777356, 0.49123304, 0.15410852]]])
```

how can this result be interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply doing this:

```
In [1108]: matrix[0]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1108]: array([0.02502891, 0.74397363, 0.74176154])

In [1109]: matrix[1]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1109]: array([0.76480152, 0.84331737, 0.29647379])

In [1110]: matrix[2]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1110]: array([0.68258943, 0.43118925, 0.82981894])
```

When you do :

```
matrix[mask]
```

where mask is :

```
matrix([[0, 0, 2],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 2]])
```

It returns you an array whose first element will be :

```
[matrix[0], matrix[0], matrix[2]],
```

2nd:

```
[matrix[1], matrix[1], matrix[0]]
```

and so on.